# Permission denied as root

Tags: linux, permissions, root

The root user of Linux doesn't have permission to read/write a regular file, unless all users have permission to read/write this file, like below:

```
drwxrwsrwx ....... file_name
```

However the owner of the file can still read/write this file.

AND:

0) not the problem of execution, just read/write
1) not the problem of device because regular user can read/write it.
2) the result of command `id`:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

so I don't think it's the problem of group.

So what other problems could be?

Comment: You may get a better response asking your question in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this filesystem on an NFS export?

Comment: yes, I guess it maybe the problem of NFS. Thx a lot

Comment: If the output is really is `drwxrwsrwx ....... file_name`and the seventh letter (`s` instead of `-` or `x`) isn't a typo, then the `s` means a `SUID` Bit is set -> ***S**(et) **U**(ser) **ID** on execution*. This means that other users can execute `*file_name*` with the *same permissions as the user who owns* `*file_name*`. But as `root` is above all users, it should be able to read the file. Guessing that you are on a GNU/Linux system: What message do you get when trying to read this file as `root` user? Also: Please describe how you do log in as `root`

Comment: In case anyone else is being stupid and winds up here, I ran into a similar issue because I was trying to delete a bunch of files in a Samba share from a different machine. I wasn't allowed to delete them, or to change the permissions, as root because the root I was using wasn't the root on the machine where the files were actually stored.

Answer (score 1):

Check mounting options like 'rw' 'ro' (read, write issues), 'user' 'exec' (execution issues).

Comment: These options affect all users not only `root`.

Answer (score -2):

chmod the files. I add issues with setting up scripts for my firewall on SlackWare 13.37, having the 'permission denied' error when trying to execute.

What I did was, for my problem, is as follows:

chmod 777 /bin/firewall-start

I don't know what exact number (777 in my case) to add after chmod command, but it's a start and I hope this helps.

Comment: chmod 777 should never be the smart solution.

Comment: The numbers are permission triplets (RWX) for user, group and other. Setting it to 777 means that the permission are set to readable, **writeable** and executable **for everyone**.  Writable for everyone is very much not desired.  Note that chmod also suppurts things like 'chmod u+x filename' to set executable for user. Much easier if you do not want to use numbers.